This NAA flag was declined, why?
I've flagged this answer to How do I cast int to enum in C#? because (as its title suggests) the question is about casting an int to enum and the answer (as it states at its very beginning : "From a string...") demonstrates how to parse the enum from a string (none of the Enum.TryParse overloads take an int, or even matches the answer's code by the way). In other words, it should be an answer to Convert a string to an enum in C# instead.
As you already know, my flag has been declined.

Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. You should downvote such answers.

Am I right to assume that a mod handled the flag given the LQA review (that was most likely gonna end up disputed) became invalidated in the answer's timeline at the same moment my flag was declined? If yes, could it be that said mod ended up declining my flag because they would've needed my detailed explanation to understand why it's NAA?

When to flag an answer as "not an answer"

@BrakNicku "You flag as NAA things posted as answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked" or if you take the image with apples (although it is intended for link only answers), this answer would definitely be the orange in that example

In my experience, this flag will be declined if it would require subject matter expertise to determine that it was in fact not an answer to the question (except in some rare cases where the mod actually is a subject matter expert.) It's important to leave a comment expressing why it isn't an answer to the question asked, not necessarily for the mods sake, but for future visitors, and to use your voting privilege to express your opinion on the usefulness of that answer to the given question. (there's nothing wrong with reiterating an older comment)

@KevinB Subject matter expertise wasn't really needed given the answer starts with "From a string...". I added to that reasons involving subject matter expertise in this question because I think if you focus on the code block and are not an expert you could indeed miss why it's not an answer to the question. I probably should've added that explanation in comments too but thought upvoting BJury's one was sufficient

This answer explains a lot, although, your flag was obviously about technical inaccuracies: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429897/6461462

Answers that simply misunderstood the question aren't Very Low Quality (see the updated duplicate list).

@nalka - I wish I knew which answer you flagged, I can't tell if it's the answer with 16 upvotes, if there is an answer that does not answer the question that was proposed I would love to vote accordingly. Sadly, an inaccurate answer, is still an answer. The only way to deal with those types of answers is to downvote them. I took a guess that "From a string: ..." is indeed the answer you are talking about.

@SecurityHound yes the link points to the answer that had a score of 16 (now 15)

From the NAA guidelines:

Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer and should not be flagged. You can add comments or downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers.

This post "attempts to answer the question," so an NAA flag is not appropriate. The poster read the question, tried their best to interpret it, and provided an answer based on their interpretation. Its technical accuracy is not relevant for flagging purposes.
Their interpretation of the question wasn't that bad, either. It's semi-reasonable to read the question as "I have an integer that is stored in a string, and I want to convert it into an enum." That's certainly not the mainstream interpretation, particularly given that int was formatted as code, but it's not ridiculous.
NAA is generally for blatantly obvious non-answers, such as "thank you," "me too," and link-only answers. Bad answers that are still answers should be voted down instead of flagged.

I thought about that interpretation too but given they didn't explain at all that TryParse would work fine if given the string representation of the corresponding integer value of the enum (nor gave informations about the value in their code), it seemed far fetched. Regarding the NAA guidelines, to me this answer really is the orange (or more like a low quality orange) in the apples example

@nalka The fact that you "thought about that interpretation" proves that NAA is inappropriate. OP was trying to answer the question. That's enough to switch the flag to a downvote at the very least.

I don't understand why we want to keep objectively off-target answers solely based on speculations (because that's all we have here), it's not like OP can't edit to (at least) turn these speculations into certainties and then undelete

@nalka downvotes still exist.

@Gimby I know and be sure I nearly always downvote something when flagging it (and that makes me wonder why it's not automatic but that's an other topic)

@nalka regarding that "why is it not automatic" question, that is indeed another topic... but worthwhile to research. Trying to link completely unrelated systems is what makes people hate Stack Overflow and leads to weekly questions like "Why is it not mandatory to explain downvotes!?"

In this case, I think the answer was trying to address an issue with the top answer by posting an updated answer (which is what our guidelines would generally suggest).  Unfortunately, the relevant part of the top answer is irrelevant to the question...though the voting suggests to me that people preferred the top answer over another answer that is more to-the-point on the actual question, so clearly people are/were, for some reason, finding value there.  It's...kind of a mess, generally.  How to address questions where this has happened might be a useful separate meta question.

Such a meta post would take the form of "How do you bypass the way the site is designed and disqualify the votes that several people have cast". No this is how it works. The way to disqualify it is to cast a downvote. One vote at a time until the score goes into the negative. Until that moment the majority has spoken - it's "good". Meta is not a way to appeal that. Neither are flags, for that matter.
